# How stop auto fill cell option when read from excel file using java

Tags: java

I read a excel file from my application using java code. It read all field's in right order,but whenever it has blank cells it auto fill with previous cell record.Here is my code

```
        ServletContext servletContext = session.getServletContext();
        File reportFile = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(sTempFile));
        FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(reportFile);
        POIFSFileSystem theFile = new POIFSFileSystem(fIS);
        m_workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(theFile);
        HSSFSheet theSheet = m_workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        //Take the first Sheet

        int col = 12;
        theSheet.setAutobreaks(true);           
        int row = theSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() + 1;


        String data[][] = new String[col][row];
        int rowCount = 1;
        while (rowCount < theSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1) {
            //Inserts all the rows except the first_row
            HSSFRow theSICDataRow = theSheet.getRow(rowCount++);
            row = rowCount - 1;
            HSSFCell cPaidAmount = null;
            if (theSICDataRow.getCell((short) 11) != null) {
                cPaidAmount = theSICDataRow.getCell((short) 11);
                if (cPaidAmount.getCellType()== HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(cPaidAmount.getNumericCellValue());
                    if (bd.intValue() == 0) {
                        sPaidAmount = "0";
                    } 
                    else {
                        sPaidAmount = String.valueOf(bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
                    }
                } 
                else if (cPaidAmount.getCellType()== HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    sPaidAmount = "" + cPaidAmount.getStringCellValue();
                }
            } 
            else if (theSICDataRow.getCell((short) 11) == null) {
                sPaidAmount = "";
            }
```

The output should be ...

Paid amount

---

1200
1200
1200
1200
1690
..
..
..
..
..
..

But it appears

Paid amount

---

1200
1200
1200
1200
1690
1690
1690
1690
1690
1690
..

The source and generated  temp file is ok,but the output show in table is in wrong .Please give some solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got my answer and want to share it , I did not handle blank cells in my code so the POIFSFileSystem auto fill the blank cells with its previous record .Here is my code

```
            HSSFCell cPaidAmount = null;
            if (theSICDataRow.getCell((short) 11) != null) {
                cPaidAmount = theSICDataRow.getCell((short) 11);

                if (cPaidAmount.getCellType()== HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(cPaidAmount.getNumericCellValue());
                    if (bd.intValue() == 0) {
                        sPaidAmount = "0";
                    } 
                    else {
                        sPaidAmount = String.valueOf(bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
                    }
                } 
                else if (cPaidAmount.getCellType()== HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    sPaidAmount = "" + cPaidAmount.getStringCellValue();
                }
                else if (cPaidAmount.getCellType()== HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    sPaidAmount = "0";
                }

            } 
            else if (theSICDataRow.getCell((short) 11) == null) {
                sPaidAmount = "0";
            }
```